# Getting error while setting up tabs in Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

While setting up the tabs in ms teams getting following error,

Unable to save the configuration for "my tab" tab

On inspecting network, https://amer.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/threads/19%3Ac05017f762dd44458a82bb57d6a855d9%40thread.skype/properties?name=tab%3A%393844f6095537dd7c51d3ad

Request Method: PUT

this request have returned the following response,

{"errorCode":201,"message":"Failure due to: InvalidParameter."}

Can't find any documentation related to this.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information, your link seems to be not working aswell.

Comment: While setting up the tab when we click on save button we get the above error. what other information you want please let me know

Comment: @Shivangi Srivastava Could you please confirm if you have given all the required parameters for [config tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration) and that your tab meets the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-requirements)?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Below I have shared my configuration file and a manifest file.

Comment: Could you please set contenturl value with a valid https url inside setsettings() method itself. Please refer to the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration#configuration-page-example).Also ensure there are no spaces and all the required fields are added.

Comment: There is no space in the URL and its a valid https URL. All the required fields have been added

Comment: Can you try adding the tab in a different channel? Could you please try login to teams in browser and check if there are any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the tab config code:

```
microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(saveEvent => {
  const origin = window.location.origin;
  const contentUrl = `${origin}/teams/index.html`;
  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
    entityId: 'example.teams.teamcontext',
    contentUrl,
    suggestedDisplayName: 'test data',
  });
  saveEvent.notifySuccess();
```

Manifest.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "id": "f1369b33-bdde-4587-908f-ttt",
  "packageName": "com.example.teams",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Test Example",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/corp/privacy-policy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/corp/terms-of-service/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Test Example",
    "full": "Test Example"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Test Example",
    "full": ""
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "",
    "color": ""
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "configurableTabs": [{
    "configurationUrl": "https://example.serveo.net/teams/index.html#/teams-configure",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "scopes": [
      "team"
    ]
  }],
  "staticTabs": [{
    "entityId": "com.example.teams",
    "name": "Test Example",
    "contentUrl": "https://example.serveo.net/teams/index.html",
    "scopes": [
      "personal"
    ]
  }],
  "bots": [{
    "botId": "d564-403f-8039-d0834b8a",
    "needsChannelSelector": false,
    "isNotificationOnly": false,
    "commandLists":[
      {
        "scopes": [
          "personal"
        ],
        "commands": [
          {
            "title": "/ti",
            "description": "Get your Todays Insigts set of cards"
          },
      }
    ],
    "scopes": [
      "team",
      "personal"
    ]
  }],
  "permissions": [],
  "validDomains": ["www.yandex.ru", "www.google.ru", "bash.org.ru", "*.example.com", "*.example.eu"]
}
```

Comment: Fixed the issue basically it's a channel issue. When I create a new channel and configure a tab on it then it works properly